# Foreach string replacement with multiple variations

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to find out the best way of going about string replacement with multiple collations.

I have a sentence which is inserted by user, i have an array which of all the miss-spelled words in that sentence and their potential corrections.

`$sentence = 'i want to recovary my vehical from the cabs';`

I want to display the following:

1. i want to recovery my vehicle from the cabs
2. i want to recover my vehicle from the cabs
3. i want to revary my vehicle from the cabs

Code so far:

```
$element = array(
    "vehical" => array('vehicle'),
    "recovary" => array('recovery', 'recover', 'revary')
);

$sentence = 'i want to recovary my vehical from the cabs';

foreach($element as $i => $val){
    echo $i;    
}
```

EDIT: Expanded another scenario:

What would happen if there was more than one variation in the top array.

```
    "vehical" => array('vehicle', 'vehiclesy', 'whatever'),
    "recovary" => array('recovery', 'recover', 'revary')
```

1. i want to recovery my vehicle from the cabs
2. i want to recovery my vehiclesy from the cabs
3. i want to recovery my whatever from the cabs
4. i want to recover my vehicle from the cabs
5. i want to recover my vehiclesy from the cabs
6. i want to recover my whatever from the cabs
7. i want to revary my vehicle from the cabs
8. i want to revary my vehiclesy from the cabs
9. i want to revary my whatever from the cabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create all unique combinations of *replacement data*. For each of those combinations you can then do the replacement. This is one way to do it:

```
<?php
function createCombinations(array $input)
{
    $head = array_shift($input);
    $tail = count($input) > 1 ? createCombinations($input) : array_shift($input);

    $combinations = [];
    foreach ($head as $left) {
        foreach ($tail as $right) {
            $combinations[] = array_merge([$left], (array) $right);
        }
    }

    return $combinations;
}

$element = [
    'vehical'  => ['vehicle', 'car'],
    'recovary' => ['recovery', 'recover', 'revary'],
    'cubs'     => ['cabs'],
];

$sentence = 'i want to recovary my vehical from the cubs';
$from = array_keys($element);

foreach (createCombinations($element) as $to) {
    echo str_replace($from, $to, $sentence), "\n";
}

# => i want to recovery my vehicle from the cabs
# => i want to recover my vehicle from the cabs
# => i want to revary my vehicle from the cabs
# => i want to recovery my car from the cabs
# => i want to recover my car from the cabs
# => i want to revary my car from the cabs
```

demo: https://ideone.com/LERb9X

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) like,

```
$str='';
foreach($element as $search => $combinations){
     foreach($combinations as $comb){
        $str.=str_replace($search,$comb,$sentence)."\n";
     }
}
echo $str;
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2d9f082f3cde92e30838c56af9209916763c9f95)

Try to make functions and create an array of all possible combinations then replace it using the resultant array like,

```
$element = array(
    "vehical" => array('vehicle', 'vehiclesy', 'whatever'),
    "recovary" => array('recovery', 'recover', 'revary')
);

$sentence = 'i want to recovary my vehical from the cabs';

// change the array using loop for replacement
function makeCombinations($combinations, $values)
{
    $res = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($combinations as $comb) {
        foreach($values as $value) {
            $res[$i] = is_array($comb) ? $comb : array($comb);
            $res[$i][] = $value;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}   

$searchArr = array();
foreach($element as $search => $values) {
    $searchArr[] = $search;
    $combinations = isset($combinations) ? makeCombinations($combinations, $values) : $values;
}

// finally replace the strings
foreach($combinations as $combination){
    echo str_replace($searchArr, $combination, $sentence),"\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff0e6528b4bac79aadf9ae117a7682471a9e3c81)

Comment: just expanded the question - apologies :(

Comment: @SophieRhodes try my answer it is working as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following solution, using a seconds (foreach and str_replace()):

```
//the items with replacement values.
$items = array(
    "vehical" => array('vehicle', 'vehiclesy', 'whatever'),
    "recovary" => array('recovery', 'recover', 'revary'),
    "cabs" => array('cups', 'cips'), 
    "from" => array(1, 2)
);

//init the initial sentence and the array with all solutions.
$sentence = 'i want to recovary my vehical from the cabs';
$solution = [];

//run through all keywords to execute the replacements.
foreach ($items as $item => $value) {
    if (count($value) > 0) {
        if (count($solution) > 0) {
            $solution = getReplacements($solution, $item, $value);
        } else {
            $solution = getReplacements($sentence, $item, $value);
        }
    }
}

//output the solutions.
array_walk_recursive($solution, 'output');

function output(&$item,$key) {
    echo $item."\n";
}

/**
 * Function to execute the replacements.
 * @param array|string $sentence An array or string on which the replacements should execute.
 * @param string $item The word which will be replaced.
 * @param array $values The replacement values for the item.
 * @return array An array with all solutions of this function.
 */
function getReplacements($sentence, $item, $values)
{
    $solutions = [];

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $sol = str_replace($item, $value, $sentence);

        if (is_array($sol)) {
            $solutions = array_merge($solutions, $sol);
        } else {
            $solutions[] = $sol;
        }
    }

    return $solutions;
}
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/X2Pg1R

Comment: just expanded the question - apologies :(

Comment: updated my answer... - working now with both arrays and without wrong sentences.